# What's the difference between a random forest model where ntrees=1 and a standard decision tree model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Is it just that the decision tree considers all data and the single tree/random forest model considers a random subset of features?

Comment: Why is this tagged `caret`?

Comment: Using caret, CART and random forest, ntrees=1 deliver different F1 scores.

Comment: This should answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif