# Why there is need to randomly select the samples from data in random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

We can also form different decision trees from same data by randomly selecting the features without creating so many samples.

Comment: What do you mean "creating so many samples"? No samples are *created* in RF

Comment: Actually, in RF we do both (i.e. randomly select both data & features); the answer here may be useful: [Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif/48239653#48239653)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting random subsets of the data is a way to make sure that each tree does not overfit the underlying data