# How do I generate a Decision Tree plot and a Variable Importance plot in Random Forest using R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, feature-selection

I am new to Data Science and I am working on a Machine Learning analysis using Random Forest algorithm to perform a classification. My target variable in my data set is called Attrition (Yes/No).

I am a bit confused as to how to generate these 2 plots in Random Fores`:

```
(1) Feature Importance Plot

(2) Decision Tree Plot
```

I understand that Random Forest is a ensemble of several Decision Tree models from the data set.

Assuming my Training data set is called `TrainDf` and my Testing data set is called `TestDf`, how can I create these 2 plots in R?

UPDATE: From these 2 posts, it seems that they cannot be done, or am I missing something here?
[Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif)

[How would you interpret an ensemble tree model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172289/how-would-you-interpret-an-ensemble-tree-model)

Comment: for plotting the (pseudo) tree structure, check out the answers to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree

Comment: The Decision Tree Plot doesn't make sense in a RF, because (as the name suggest) there are multiple Trees, each is a little (or a lot) different from the other. So you can't make one single plot, unless somehow you average all those trees (not very useful). The importance plot can be done, see the first answer here.

Comment: OP possibly wants to be able to print any decision tree from the forest, which can be done with the `getTree` function

Comment: @RLave I am confused as to which answer your link refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot the variable importance, you can use the below code.

```
mtcars.rf <- randomForest(am ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                      importance=TRUE)
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Feature importance plot** with `ggplot2`,

```
library(randomForest)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars.rf <- randomForest(vs ~ ., data=mtcars)
imp <- cbind.data.frame(Feature=rownames(mtcars.rf$importance),mtcars.rf$importance)
g <- ggplot(imp, aes(x=reorder(Feature, -IncNodePurity), y=IncNodePurity))
g + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + xlab('Feature')
```

[image]

**A Decision Tree plot** with `igraph` (a tree from the random forest)

```
tree <- randomForest::getTree(mtcars.rf, k=1, labelVar=TRUE) # get the 1st decision tree with k=1
tree$`split var` <- as.character(tree$`split var`)
tree$`split point` <- as.character(tree$`split point`)
tree[is.na(tree$`split var`),]$`split var` <- ''
tree[tree$`split point` == '0',]$`split point` <- ''

library(igraph)
gdf <- data.frame(from = rep(rownames(tree), 2),
                          to = c(tree$`left daughter`, tree$`right daughter`))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(gdf, directed=TRUE)
V(g)$label <- paste(tree$`split var`, '\r\n(', tree$`split point`, ',', round(tree$prediction,2), ')')
g <- delete_vertices(g, '0')
print(g, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)
plot(g, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1), vertex.size=5, vertex.color='cyan')
```

As can be seen from the following plot, the the label for each node in the decision tree represents the variable name chosen for split at that node, (the split value, the proportion of class with label 1) at that node.

[image]

Likewise the 100th tree can be obtained with `k=100` with the  `randomForest::getTree()` function which looks like the following

[image]