# Random Subspace Method in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Any idea on how to implement "Random Subspace Method" (an ensemble method) as described by (Ho,1998) in R?
Can't find a package

> Ho, Tin Kam (1998). "[The Random Subspace Method for Constructing Decision Forests](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Random-Subspace-Method-for-Constructing-Forests-Ho/b41d0fa5fdaadd47fc882d3db04277d03fb21832)". IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence. 20 (8): 832–844.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, this has been "integrated" (kind of) into the Random Forest (RF) algorithm - it is in fact the random selection of features controlled by the `mtry` argument in the standard R package `randomForest`; see the [Wikipedia entry on RF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest), as well as the answer (disclaimer: mine) in the SO thread [Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif/48239653#48239653) for more details.

While replicating the exact behavior of the said algorithm in the scikit-learn implementation of RF is easy and straightforward (just set `bootstrap=False` - see linked thread above), I'll confess that I cannot think of a way to get the same behavior from the `randomForest` R package - i.e. "force" it to not use bootstrap sampling, which would make it equivalent to the Random Subspace method; I have tried the combination of `replace=FALSE` and `sampsize=nrow(x)` in the [`randomForest` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest), but it doesn't seem to work...

All in all, the message here (and arguably the reason why there is not a specific implementation of the method in R or other frameworks) is that, most probably, you will be better off sticking to Random Forests; if you *definitely* want to experiment with it, AFAIK the only option seems to be Python and scikit-learn.

Comment: Original RSM only selects a subset at the beginning of the tree construction. In fact, the author says:  _"More different trees can be
constructed if the subspace changes within the trees, that is,
if different feature dimensions are selected at each split"_          [algorithm section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_subspace_method)

Comment: I suppose a way to implement RSM in R could be achieved with a generic _ensemble_ function i could just feed with some models.

Answer (score 1):

Found this function in *caret* package:

```
model<-bag(x=iris[,-5], y=iris[,5], vars = 2, 
bagControl = bagControl(fit = ctreeBag$fit,
                        predict = ctreeBag$pred,
                        aggregate = ctreeBag$aggregate), 
trControl=trainControl(method = 'none'))
```

It supports *vars* attribute so you can consider a random subset of variables for each learner; at the same time bootstrap sampling can be avoided by passing *method = 'none'* as a parameter.