# Neural network for adding two integer numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to create a neural network which can add two integer numbers. I have designed it as follows:

**question**  I have really low accuracy of 0.002% . what can i do to increase it?

1. For creating data:

   import numpy as np
   import random
   a=[]
   b=[]
   c=[]

   for i in range(1, 1001):
   a.append(random.randint(1,999))
   b.append(random.randint(1,999))
   c.append(a[i-1] + b[i-1])

   X = np.array([a,b]).transpose()
   y = np.array(c).transpose().reshape(-1, 1)
2. scaling my data :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
minmax = MinMaxScaler()
minmax2 = MinMaxScaler()
X = minmax.fit_transform(X)
y = minmax2.fit_transform(y)
```

3. The network :

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

clfa = Sequential()
clfa.add(Dense(input_dim=2, output_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
clfa.add(Dense(output_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
clfa.add(Dense(output_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
clfa.add(Dense(output_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
clfa.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='relu'))

opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
clfa.compile(opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['acc'])
clfa.fit(X, y, epochs=140)
```

outputs :

```
Epoch 133/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020
Epoch 134/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020   
Epoch 135/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020
Epoch 136/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020
Epoch 137/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020
Epoch 138/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 42us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020   
Epoch 139/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020   
Epoch 140/140
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 42us/step - loss: 0.0012 - acc: 0.0020
```

That is my code with console outputs..

I have tried every different combinations of optimizers, losses, and activations, plus this data fits perfectly a Linear Regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes, several issues.

The mistakes:

- This is a regression problem, so the activation of the last layer should be `linear`, not `relu` (leaving it without specifying anything will work, since `linear` is the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) activation in a Keras layer).
- Accuracy is [meaningless in regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse); remove `metrics=['acc']` from your model compilation - you should judge the performance of your model only with your loss.

The issues:

- We don't use `sigmoid` activations for the intermediate layers; change all of them to `relu`.
- Remove the `kernel_initializer` argument, thus leaving the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) `glorot_uniform`, which is the recommended one.
- A number of Dense layers each one only with two nodes is not a good idea; try reducing the number of layers and increasing the number of nodes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234347/why-im-getting-bad-result-with-keras-vs-random-forest-or-knn) for a simple example network for the iris data.

Comment: i huge thanks . You are like more than teacher for me. I removed weightinit and used linear activation reeuces layers and now i have accurate predictions and very low loss but accuracy is still 0.002 no matter I have good predictions.

Comment: Please notice what I have said in answer: accuracy is **meaningless** in regression, and you should **not** use it. Performance assessment should be done exactly based upon loss and quality of predictions.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks i got it

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to fit a linear function, but internally use sigmoid nodes, which map values to a range (0,1). Sigmoid is very useful for classification, but not really for regression if the values are outside (0,1). It could MAYBE work if you restricted your random number to floating point in the interval [0,1]. OR input into your nodes all the bits seperately, and have it learn an adder.

Comment: That is why i preprocessed data. Which converted value from 0-1 so my whole dataset in above example is (0,1) values

Comment: The values have been normalized before; `sigmoid` is indeed never used in practice for intermediate layers, but not for the reason you imply here.

Comment: @NanduRaj https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks) I have to admit I don't have much experience with neural networks, so I guess my knowledge might be a bit outdated. According to wikipedia since 2011 relu is preferred over sigmoid in intermediate layers. A few advantages are listed.